# ¿Cómo realizar la interseccion en phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Quiero realizar una consulta en `phpmyadmin` pero `MariaDB` no soporta la intersección y no se como hacer la siguiente consulta.

Pretendo obtener la raza y el nombre de los caballos que su disciplina sea salto fondo y también salto vertical, hay que realizarlo en dos tablas diferentes que se encuentran unidas por dos campos que en una se llama `Cod` y en la otra `Caballo` he intentado hacer la siguiente consulta pero no me sale ningún campo.

```
SELECT c.Raza, c.Nombre 
FROM caballos c JOIN caballodisciplina d 
ON c.Cod = d.Caballo 
WHERE d.Disciplina IN ('Salto fondo','Salto vertical') 
GROUP BY c.Raza, c.Nombre 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.Cod) = 2
```

Las tablas que utilizadas son las que se pueden ver en las siguientes imagenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y debería de salir el siguiente resultado

```
+------------+------------+
| Nombre     | Raza       |
+------------+------------+
| Starlaight | Andaluz    |
+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Por favor, añade la estructura de las tablas que estas utilizando junto a algunas filas de ejemplo

Comment: Ya he añadido una imagen de las tablas que son utilizadas

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien, quieres los caballos que tienen exactamente las 2 disciplinas `Salto fondo` y `Salto vertical`, ni más, ni menos.

Si eso es lo que pides, una manera de hacer la consulta es de esta manera. Nota que la lógica se concentra en la claúsula `HAVING`:

```
SELECT c.Raza, c.Nombre 
  FROM caballos c
  JOIN caballodisciplina d 
    ON c.Cod = d.Caballo 
 GROUP BY c.Cod, c.Raza, c.Nombre
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.Disciplina) = 2
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN d.Disciplina = 'Salto fondo' THEN 'X' END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN d.Disciplina = 'Salto vertical' THEN 'X' END) > 0
```

Si por otro lado, el deseo es que la consulta devuelva los caballos que por lo menos tienen esas 2 disciplinas, pero que puedan tener otras además, entonces la consulta pudiera ser simplemente:

```
SELECT c.Raza, c.Nombre 
  FROM caballos c
  JOIN caballodisciplina d 
    ON c.Cod = d.Caballo 
 GROUP BY c.Cod, c.Raza, c.Nombre
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN d.Disciplina IN ('Salto fondo','Salto vertical') THEN d.Disciplina END) = 2
```

... o tal vez un poco más sencillo:

```
SELECT c.Raza, c.Nombre 
  FROM caballos c
  JOIN caballodisciplina d 
    ON c.Cod = d.Caballo
   AND d.Disciplina IN ('Salto fondo','Salto vertical')
 GROUP BY c.Cod, c.Raza, c.Nombre
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.Disciplina) = 2
```